# Antiderivatives and integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I need to find
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_1^x\frac{du}{u^2}$$

I can integrate $\frac{1}{u^2}$ to get $-\frac{1}{2u}$ but then I am stuck as to what to do next.

Comment: Well, suppose you've integrated (there's a small mistake right now), so all that's left is substituting the lower and upper endpoints and then computing the derivative.

Answer (score 3):

$$\int\limits_1^x\frac{du}{u^2}=\left.-\frac1u\right|_1^x=-\frac1x+1$$

Well, now just differentiate the right hand side wrt $\;x\;$...

Answer (score 3):

$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\int_{1}^{x}\dfrac{du}{u^2}=\dfrac{1}{x^2}$$

Comment: Note that the [first Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part) has been used here.